# Blender to Unity Weird Transforms

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

When exporting a scene from Blender to Unity, the position and rotation of some objects become messed up. The screenshots below illustrate the problem:

[image: Blender]
[image: Unity]

I'm using Blender 2.79b and Unity 2018.2.0f2. I'm running macOS High Sierra. The screenshots above illustrate importing the blend file with the default settings in Unity. The same happens when I convert to FBX in Blender and import in Unity (using default export settings in Blender). All objects have object transforms applied in Blender. The barrel segments that are out of place (1) are parented to the swivel joints (2), which in turn are parented to a bone (3). There is no animation.

If I unparent everything in blender and keep object transforms, everything looks good.

Comment: I would suggest try playing with Settings in Add Import Settings -> Models by selecting the model. I have not yet encountered this problem though. You can start with Checking on/off Optimize Mesh, ImportBlendshapes. Try over here first and post what exactly is the output after changing the values in Model section.

Comment: Is it possible to get your fbx file, to test some settings in unity? Because with my simple models I didn't have this problem.

Comment: @killer_mech Thank you for the comment. I've tried your suggestions. Unfortunately, most settings do nothing (I've tried most of them that seemed relevant). The only setting that does anything is disabling the rig - moving from animation type "Generic" to "None". This affects the model due to the fact that some objects are parented straight to the bone.

Comment: @xFL Sorry, but due to the nature of the project I can't share the FBX file.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone having the same issue - I've managed to resolve it by clearing all parents, and reparenting using empty vertex groups instead of parenting directly to bones.